# Select values, then only call function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I will use a [jsfillde](https://jsfiddle.net/bmun0mkx/1/) used previously.

As you can see when clicking on a filter (soup, meat, etc.), filtered result load in **real time**. I would like instead to let the user make the selection and **then** trigger the result by cliking a"update" button (to enhcance performances on mobile)

I am quite unsure about how to acheive this in JavaScript, I am very new..I am using Ionic, and below is the HTML piece to call the filter function.

```
 <ion-item ng-repeat="dish in dishList | selectedDishType:selection ">
        <article class="item_frame">
                <h1 class="item_name_english">{{dish.nameEnglish}}</h1>

                <h2 class="item_name_local_language">{{dish.nameLocal}}</h2>

            <p class="item_description ">{{dish.description}}</p>
        </article>
        <!--main article frame 1 -->
    </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a button :

```
    <div class="listing_venue_types_filter_page">
        <div class="input_dishtype_selection " data-ng-repeat="dishType in dishTypeList" ng-class="{'filter_selected':selection.indexOf($index) != -1}" ng-click="toggle($index)">{{dishType.name}}</div>
    </div>
    <button class="button" ng-click="updateDisplay()">Update</button>
```

and in the controller :
move the emit action to a new scope function

```
  $scope.updateDisplay = function () {
     //calling an event to any listener with the latest selection data.
        $rootScope.$emit('dishType.selectionChanged', $scope.dishTypeList.filter(function (dType, idx) {
            return $scope.selection.indexOf(idx) != -1;
        }).map(function (dType) {
            return dType.name.toLowerCase();
        }));
        //calling an event to any listener with the latest selection data.
    };
```

Comment: have no  idea, console doesn't show any error. Selection works fine, but when calling function from the button results do not update at all

Comment: Edit your post with the local code. I can't guess your problem.

Comment: when you say " the selection works fine ", you mean "displaying dish selection works fine " ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74327/discussion-between-calden-and-lauwm).